# Can't show the date picker dialog in a fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-datepicker

I'm trying to implement a date picker dialog in the insert fragment. Inside the insert fragment, I add a button to show the date picker dialog and show the selected date in the text view.

**Problem**

when I try to run the code it shows those errors.

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is AddFragment but Context was expected
Type mismatch: inferred type is String but Editable? was expected
```

inside of Add Fragment.kt file,

it shows red underline to `this` & `view` keyword from `dobDatePicker()` function.

Note: I'm using the `view binding` for calling UI id's.

Here is the code of `fragment_add.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context=".fragments.add.AddFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!-- NSU ID INPUT-->
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/nsu_id"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/nsu_id"
            app:endIconMode="clear_text"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/selected_date"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="7"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MdcTypographyStyles.Subtitle1"
                android:typeface="normal" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <!-- Student name-->
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/student_name"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:hint="@string/student_name"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:endIconMode="clear_text"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nsu_id">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MdcTypographyStyles.Subtitle1"
                android:typeface="normal" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <!-- School list-->
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/school_list_dropdown"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:hint="@string/select_academic_school"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/student_name">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="none"
                tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <!-- Department list-->
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/department_list_dropdown"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:hint="@string/department_name"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/school_list_dropdown">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="none"
                tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <!-- Date of birth text field-->
        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@id/selected_date"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:hint="@string/date_of_birth"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MdcTypographyStyles.Subtitle1"
            android:typeface="normal"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/department_list_dropdown" />

        <!-- date picker button -->

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/datePicker_button"
            android:layout_width="52dp"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:insetLeft="0dp"
            android:insetTop="0dp"
            android:insetRight="0dp"
            android:insetBottom="0dp"
            app:icon="@drawable/ic_outline_calendar_today_24"
            app:iconGravity="textStart"
            app:iconPadding="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/selected_date"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/selected_date"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/selected_date"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

        <!-- Phone number-->

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/phone_number"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:hint="@string/phone_number"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:endIconMode="clear_text"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/selected_date">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:maxLength="11"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MdcTypographyStyles.Subtitle1"
                android:typeface="normal" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <!-- NID number-->
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/nid_number"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:hint="@string/nid_number"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:endIconMode="clear_text"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/phone_number">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="10"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MdcTypographyStyles.Subtitle1"
                android:typeface="normal" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <!-- Present Address-->
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/present_address"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:hint="@string/present_address"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:endIconMode="clear_text"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nid_number">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MdcTypographyStyles.Subtitle1"
                android:typeface="normal" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <!-- Permanent Address-->
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/permanent_address"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:hint="@string/permanent_address"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:endIconMode="clear_text"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/present_address">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MdcTypographyStyles.Subtitle1"
                android:typeface="normal" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <!-- Submit button -->
        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/submit_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
            android:text="@string/submit"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MdcTypographyStyles.Button"
            android:typeface="normal"
            app:elevation="2dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/permanent_address" />


        <!--Constraint layout finish-->
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Here is the code of `AddFragment.kt`:

```kotlin
package com.example.studentinfodb.fragments.add

import android.app.DatePickerDialog
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.example.studentinfodb.R
import com.example.studentinfodb.databinding.FragmentAddBinding
import java.util.*


class AddFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentAddBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        _binding = FragmentAddBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val view = binding.root

        /*
        Academic school dropdown lists with array adapter
         */

        val schoolNames = listOf(
            "School of Business & Economics",
            "School of Humanities & Social " +
                    "Sciences",
            "School of Engineering & Physical Sciences",
            "School of Health & Life Sciences"
        )

        val schoolAdapter = ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), R.layout.school_list, schoolNames)
        (binding.schoolListDropdown.editText as? AutoCompleteTextView)?.setAdapter(schoolAdapter)


        /*
       Department names dropdown lists with array adapter
        */

        val departmentNames = listOf(
            "Accounting & Finance",
            "Economics",
            "Management",
            "Marketing & International Business",
            "MBA & EMBA Programs"
        )

        val departmentAdapter =
            ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), R.layout.school_list, departmentNames)
        (binding.departmentListDropdown.editText as? AutoCompleteTextView)?.setAdapter(
            departmentAdapter
        )

        /*
        Date picker for date of birth
         */




        binding.datePickerButton.setOnClickListener {
            dobDatePicker()
        }

        return view
    }

    private fun dobDatePicker() {
        /*
        pick date from calender
         */
        val myCalender = Calendar.getInstance()
        val year = myCalender.get(Calendar.YEAR)
        val month = myCalender.get(Calendar.MONTH)
        val day = myCalender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

        // open the dialog
        val datePicker = DatePickerDialog(
            this,
            DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { view, selectedYear, selectedMonth, selectedDayOfMonth ->
                // date format
                val selectedDate = "$selectedDayOfMonth/ ${selectedMonth + 1}/ $selectedYear"

                // show the date in text view
                binding.selectedDate.text = selectedDate
            }, year, month, day
        )
        // restriction for the future date selection
        datePicker.datePicker.maxDate = Date().time - 86400000
        // visible the date picker dialog
        datePicker.show()


    }


}
```

Here is the code of `MainActivity.kt`:

```kotlin
package com.example.studentinfodb

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
/*
Change the name of the action bar
 */
        setupActionBarWithNavController(findNavController(R.id.fragment))
    }


}
```

Thank you.

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at how to produce a [mre]. It's not very helpful to have to go through all your code when there is only a couple of lines that are causing the error.

Comment: For the first error, a `Fragment` is not a context. You might have got it mixed up with using `this` whilst in an `Activity` which *is* a context. You can obtain the context with `Fragment.getContext()`.

Comment: For the second error, I'm not sure what you're referring to. If you're taking about the `view` in the `DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener` then it doesn't make much sense that it is saying it's a string, so maybe product that [mre] and see what the issue is then.

Comment: you just should change context from this to requireContext() and everything will working fine

Comment: I do use `requireContext()` but won't work. @hudaOlayan